# Porting NSString to NSData to Android

Tags: java, android, iphone, objective-c

We're currently porting one of the projects from Objective-C to Java.

Byte data is coming from a server encoded to a string, and we're converting it to a byte array.

[Objective-C]:

```
NSString * imageString = @"abcde......"; //quite a long string
NSData * imageData = [imageString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
constant Byte * imageBytes = [imageData bytes];
```

Now, I'm trying to do the same on Android

[JAVA]:

```
String imageString = "abcde......"; //quite a long string
byte [] imageBytes = imageString.getData("UTF-16");
```

However, if I compare imageBytes arrays from the first and second snippets, they are different. I presume that this has to do with the UTF-16 encoding that I'm using in Java case (there's no such option as 'Unicode', I guess).

Is there any work around this?

Comment: Try UTF-8 encoding... For iOS that would be `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: It may be an endianess issue, by default the iphone will encode that as little endian. This will include a byte order mark that the Java code should be able to read and display properly. You could, however, try `[imageString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];` This will not include the byte order mark so you will be missing the `FEFF` prefix. I recommend creating a small string like above and adding the hex representation from both to your post.